# How to export products in google feed format from phpmyadmin magento 2

Tags: magento2, export, google

I want a text file with all the products with below columns:
**id**, **title**, **description**, **link**, **image_link**, **availability**, **price**, **sale_price**

How can I export this data from phpMyAdmin?

**I am using Magento 2.3.3**

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not save Product data in a single table. It is using an Eav Structure for saving Product attribute data.So first you have to understand this Eav structure then you able to get your required data.

- https://belvg.com/blog/eav-in-magento-2.html
- https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/list-of-product-tables-in-magento/
- https://inchoo.net/magento/magentos-database-layout-and-its-eav-structure/

At Magento's, `id, title, description, link, image_link` are eav attributes and  Product main table `catalog_product_entity`.

You can find attributes table type from `eav_attribute` by running  below query:

> SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = 4

Magento 2,`entity_type_id` for the product is  4 and that why I added condition ``entity_type_id = 4`

From `backend_type`  column  of  `eav_attribute` table, you understand the table for save that attribute value like `description` backend type is `text`.it means
value save for this attribute at `catalog_product_entity_text`

So, you need to build a Mysql joining query on  table  `catalog_product_entity` respective table with attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply sir.

Sorry, I am not that expert to run queries using join commands. Is there any 
pre-developed query to get the results that I want. Please help me if any.